# In mosh how can I scrollback in the terminal and use mouse in emacs, less etc

Tags: scroll, emacs, mosh

I want to use `mouse-wheel` in `emacs` and also scroll-back in the terminal history. When I do `mosh --no-init` I can scroll-back in the terminal history but I cannot use mouse wheel in the `emacs`. Instead if I do only `mosh` without `--no-init` flag I can use mouse-scroll in Emacs but cannot scroll back in the terminal history. I get lost in finding solution to fix this.

In mosh is it possible to scroll-back in the terminal history along with using mouse wheel in `emacs`, `nano`, `less`?

---

[mosh prevents the use of scrollback #122](https://github.com/mobile-shell/mosh/issues/122#issuecomment-623792008)

> The root cause of not able to scroll is caused by `mosh` entering a
> "alternative screen" mode. It can be disabled using the --no-init flag
> ([see the doc](https://github.com/mobile-shell/mosh/issues/122#issuecomment-623792008)). Just `alias mosh='mosh --no-init'` and the problem
> will go away.

Developers argue that:

> I don't consider using `--no-init` as a way to get reliable access to a local scroll-back buffer. But please interpret this open issue as simply an acknowledgement of the request. **We do not have any intention on implementing this feature**

And [recommended me from a issue I opened](https://github.com/mobile-shell/mosh/issues/1110) to use `screen` or `tmux` as a solution. But I was not able to make them work. Where when I use `tmux` inside the remote machine I experience that:

- Scroll-back in the terminal history works, but it prevents me to copy some text from previois terminal history, it jumps back to current cursor spot right away.
- Scroll-back does not work within `emacs, less, nano` etc.

---

My comment in their [repsonde to mosh prevents the use of scrollback #122](https://github.com/mobile-shell/mosh/issues/122#issuecomment-623792008) labelled as `This comment was marked as off-topic.`, which was what I mentioned in this question.

---

Their issue [related to mosh prevents the use of scrollback #122](https://github.com/mobile-shell/mosh/issues/122) was open since 2012, which is around 8 years and I believe it is abandoned. If it is implemented it was implemented by now.

**Contributors of `mosh` ignoring this issue.** and saying `There is hundreds of subscribers. Please think very carefully before commenting` . // There was not hundreds of subscribers in the thread.

In summary, I am not having issue with `--no-init`, I am having issue with `mosh` related to `mosh prevents the use of scrollback #122` , which does not support scroll back in terminal history along within tools like `emacs, nano, vim, vi, less, more` and so on. If a developer switching from `ssh` to `mosh` there is no way he/she can adapt the scroll behavior of `mosh`. Without having both together like `ssh` does, there is no meaning to use `mosh` at all.